# Tanuki Software Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, windows-services, wrapper, java-service-wrapper, yajsw

I am using Tanuki Java service wrapper for my application, 
My application restarts frequently eventually giving "5 failed launches in a row, giving up". 
here is my wrapper

```
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/18 13:22:39 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 00:24:17 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 00:24:17 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 01:07:33 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 01:08:11 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 01:08:11 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 05:31:55 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 05:32:34 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 05:32:34 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 13:33:23 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 13:33:23 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 16:07:30 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 17:02:46 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 20:17:36 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 20:18:13 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 20:18:13 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/19 21:27:08 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 00:28:00 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 00:28:00 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 05:22:27 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 05:22:27 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 13:47:37 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 16:27:34 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 18:22:28 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 18:22:28 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 19:22:21 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:06 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:08 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:08 | Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.7
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:08 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:08 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/05/20 21:28:08 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/05/20 21:28:09 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
```

Any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: have you set the class path of java

Comment: yes class path for Java is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your full wrapper.log file?  From the times and order of messages, it looks like you may be only showing us specific lines.

Usually the failed invocations indicate a configuration problem.  I would need to see the wrapper.conf file as well as the full wrapper.log output with wrapper.debug=true enabled to tell you the problem.

As you are a professional edition user, please contact us at support@tanukisoftware.com and we would be happy to help you get this resolved.
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/support.jsp

Cheers,
Leif